# JSON variable returning correct but value is undefined?

Tags: json, variables

Here is my success function for my ajax request via jquery,

```
success: function(response) {

    if (response.error == undefined) {

    alert(response);
    }
$('#' + id).after('<div id="emailMsg" class="error">' + response.error + '</div>');

}
```

Because the value is coming back as undefined it alerts me the returned JSON which is...

```
{"error":true}
```

Why is this happening, surely when I call response.error I should get either true or false.

**UPDATE**

Variable is returning as a string and not boolean, my json_encode();

```
    if (!$q -> rowCount()) {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
}
else {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try adding the `dataType: 'json'` parameter to your `$.ajax` call. That will ensure that jQuery will take care of making the response an object for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse the JSON from a string into a JavaScript object.

This can be done with `JSON.parse(response)`. In old browsers that don't have native JSON, `eval(response)` works too, but is less secure.

Comment: Just tried it, adding it in before the if statement, does not work :/

Comment: Try `alert(typeof response);` and see what it gives you.

Comment: It returns string, I have edited my question to show you my json_encode();

Comment: Okay, and are you doing `response = JSON.parse(response);`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Tarek Fadel's solution worked just fine.